# List reformating in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, formatting

I have this df:

```
   KEGGnumber         Cor             Colors
X1 C00095            -2.623973e-01    RED
X2 C17714, C00044    -2.241113e-01    RED
X3 C00033            -3.066684e-01    RED
```

and would like to format it as a two column dataframe with each individual `KEGGnumber` to be matched with its `Color`. It would look something like this:

```
KEGGnumber  Colors
C00095      RED
C17714      RED
C00044      RED
C00033      RED
```

Essentially, the new dataframe take the rows of the old dataframe with more than one `KEGGnumber` and splits them up, while keeping the same `Color` for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr` makes this quite easy:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% separate_rows(KEGGnumber)
##          Cor Colors KEGGnumber
## 1 -0.2623973    RED     C00095
## 2 -0.2241113    RED     C17714
## 3 -0.2241113    RED     C00044
## 4 -0.3066684    RED     C00033
```

Chop off the `Cor` column if you like.

A less-pretty base option:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        Map(function(x, y){data.frame(KEGGnumber = x, Colors = y)}, 
            strsplit(as.character(df$KEGGnumber), ', '), 
            df$Colors))
##   KEGGnumber Colors
## 1     C00095    RED
## 2     C17714    RED
## 3     C00044    RED
## 4     C00033    RED
```

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be a duplicate, but a very similar question can be found here: [Splitting a string into new rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401505/splitting-a-string-into-new-rows-in-r).

A simple adaptation of this example to your case would be:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
df2 <- as.data.frame(cSplit(as.data.frame(ls), "KEGGnumber",
                                     sep = ",", direction = "long"))

df2
  KEGGnumber        Cor Colors
1     c00095 -0.2623973    RED
2     c17714 -0.2241113    RED
3     c00044 -0.2241113    RED
4     c00033 -0.3066684    RED
```