# Split multiple comma-separated column into separate rows

Tags: r

I have a data set containing two columns:

```
Quantity    SKU
1,1         2494008,2493953
1,1,1       2167550,1336380,2365409
3,2,1,6,1   1428608,1137956,2401393,2679310,2579183
```

End state is a data set that looks like this:

```
Quantity    SKU
1           2494008
1           2493953
1           2167550
1           1336380
1           2365409
3           1428608
2           1137956
1           2401393
6           2679310
1           2579183
```

cplit and strsplit work if you want to split on a single variable as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-delimited-strings-in-a-column-and-insert-as-new-rows), but I need to split on two vars (Quantity and SKU from above).

Comment: There are lots of dupes for this.  Please check `?cSplit` from `splitstackshape` or `separate_rows` from `tidyr`

Comment: There was a very similar question to this only a few hours ago.

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401505/splitting-a-string-into-new-rows-in-r

Comment: appreciate everyone's feedback.  discovered a straightforward solution after diving deeper into the cSplit function.  script looks like this: `cSplit(product_report, c('Quantity','SKU'),',',direction = 'long')`

Answer (score 1):

With `separate_rows` from `tidyr`:

```
df <- read.table(text="Quantity    SKU
1,1         2494008,2493953
1,1,1       2167550,1336380,2365409
3,2,1,6,1   1428608,1137956,2401393,2679310,2579183",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tidyr)
df %>% separate_rows(Quantity,SKU)

   Quantity     SKU
      <chr>   <chr>
1         1 2494008
2         1 2493953
3         1 2167550
4         1 1336380
5         1 2365409
6         3 1428608
7         2 1137956
8         1 2401393
9         6 2679310
10        1 2579183
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- read.table(text="Quantity    SKU
1,1         2494008,2493953
1,1,1       2167550,1336380,2365409
3,2,1,6,1   1428608,1137956,2401393,2679310,2579183", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat2<-data.frame(Quantity = unlist(strsplit(dat$Quantity, split=",")), 
             SKU=unlist(strsplit(dat$SKU, split=",")), row.names = NULL)

dat3 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(dat, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))))

# Quantity     SKU
# 1         1 2494008
# 2         1 2493953
# 3         1 2167550
# 4         1 1336380
# 5         1 2365409
# 6         3 1428608
# 7         2 1137956
# 8         1 2401393
# 9         6 2679310
# 10        1 2579183
```

Comment: easier dat3 is `dat3 <- data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ","))))`.

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly, the `data.table` solution is quite similar to the base R solution proposed [by lmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808502/split-multiple-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows#comment76598421_44808628):

```
library(data.table)
data.table(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))]
```

> ```
>     Quantity     SKU
>  1:        1 2494008
>  2:        1 2493953
>  3:        1 2167550
>  4:        1 1336380
>  5:        1 2365409
>  6:        3 1428608
>  7:        2 1137956
>  8:        1 2401393
>  9:        6 2679310
> 10:        1 2579183
> ```

The row number can be kept if required:

```
data.table(dat)[, rn := .I][, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ","))), rn]
```

> ```
>     rn Quantity     SKU
>  1:  1        1 2494008
>  2:  1        1 2493953
>  3:  2        1 2167550
>  4:  2        1 1336380
>  5:  2        1 2365409
>  6:  3        3 1428608
>  7:  3        2 1137956
>  8:  3        1 2401393
>  9:  3        6 2679310
> 10:  3        1 2579183
> ```

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(Quantity = c("1,1", "1,1,1", "3,2,1,6,1"), SKU = c("2494008,2493953", 
"2167550,1336380,2365409", "1428608,1137956,2401393,2679310,2579183"
)), .Names = c("Quantity", "SKU"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```